# FileStream.SetLength: Are the contents of the stream between the old and the new length really undefined, or are they zeros?

Tags: c#, linux, filesystems, coreclr, c#-7.3

The [FileStream.SetLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.setlength?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation says:

> the contents of the stream between the old and the new length are
>   undefined

But [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150710-00/?p=45171) says:

> The most basic way of doing this is to use Set­File­Pointer to move
>   the pointer to a large position into the file (that doesn't exist
>   yet), then use Set­End­Of­File to extend the file to that size. This
>   file has disk space assigned to it, but NTFS doesn't actually fill the
>   bytes with zero yet. It will do that lazily on demand.

It says NTFS fills the bytes with zero lazily.

I guess `FileStream.SetLength` call `SetFilePointer` and `SetEndOfFile` under the hoods.

UPDATE:
The blog post also says:

> Bonus chatter: The documentation for Set­End­Of­File says, "If the
>   file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end of the
>   file and the new end of the file are not defined." But I just said
>   that it will be filled with zero on demand. Who is right?
>
> The formal definition of the Set­End­Of­File function is that the
>   extended content is undefined. However, NTFS will ensure that you
>   never see anybody else's leftover data, for security reasons.
>   (Assuming you're not intentionally bypassing the security by using
>   Set­File­Valid­Data.)
>
> Other file systems, however, may choose to behave differently

So, It seems that on NTFS systems file zeroing is guaranteed.

END UPDATE

[SetFileValidData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata) documentation says:

> The SetFileValidData function allows you to avoid filling data with
>   zeros when writing nonsequentially to a file

It seems to say that if you don't call `SetFileValidData` the file is filled with zeros.

So the question is:

**Are the contents of the stream between the old and the new length really undefined, or are they zeros?**

Context: Windows 10, NTFS, Net Framework 4.72.

**I'd also like to ask about coreclr Linux and other file systems.**

**If you don't call `SetFileValidData`, in which cases that content might be non zero?**

I'm asking because I'm developing [PersistentHashing](https://github.com/jesuslpm/PersistentHashing) an open source projects that relies on zero filling.

I've written a small program that looks for non zero values, but it never finds one:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestZeros
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.WriteLine("Searching non zeros ...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            try
            {
                var testTask = Test(cs.Token);
                var readLineTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    cs.Cancel();
                });
                long nonZeroValue = await testTask;
                Console.WriteLine($"Found {nonZeroValue} in the file");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Non zero values couldn't be found");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: \n" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        static unsafe Task<long> Test(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    const int OneGigabyte = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "mmap.bin");

                    // create mmap file and accessor, then adquire pointer 
                    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    fileStream.SetLength(OneGigabyte);

                    var mmap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileStream, null, fileStream.Length,
                        MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,
                        null, HandleInheritability.None, true);

                    var accessor = mmap.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    byte* baseAddress = null;
                    accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref baseAddress);
                    byte* endAddress = baseAddress + OneGigabyte;
                    try
                    {
                        long* pointer = (long*)baseAddress;
                        while (pointer < endAddress)
                        {
                            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException();
                            if (*pointer != 0) return *pointer;
                            pointer++;
                        }
                        pointer = (long*)baseAddress;
                        while (pointer < endAddress)
                        {
                            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) throw new OperationCanceledException();
                            *pointer = -1L;
                            pointer++;
                        }
                        accessor.Flush();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
                        accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.Close();
                        accessor.Dispose();
                        mmap.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle.Close();
                        mmap.Dispose();
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not confuse `FileStream` with one specific file system like NTFS. FileStreams can operate on a number of different file systems that might be local or remote (accessed through SMB, for example). Thus, FileStream cannot make a single assumption about how different file systems (or implementations for shared access to file storage, such as SMB) behave. Hence "undefined".

Comment: In terms of what `FileStream.SetLength` does under the hood, just look at its implementation: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#212c0536642e78d6 (in short, yes it uses SetEndOfFile to set file size)

Comment: @elgonzo, so in Windows 10, NTFS and local internal hard disk. Will files be zeroed?

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: @elgonzo I tried, did you see the small program?

Comment: If you tried already for yourself, why do you ask me what happens "in Windows 10, NTFS and local internal hard disk"...? Is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: @elgonzo because I need guaranties.

Comment: Why do you think a random guy on the internet like me can give you guarantees about whether Windows 10 will _always_ behave like you observed or not? Perhaps it currently does, perhaps with the next update desaster it won't anymore. Who knows with W10... Go ask Microsoft (or one of their evangelists) directly ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I ask on StackOverflow because there are expert people. If you don't know for sure, bud luck.

Comment: Yes, some people here are experts (i am not including me). But that doesn't mean they know what Microsoft will do next with Windows 10 and NTFS. Before Windows 10, i would argue that the blog post you linked to (offical! Microsoft blog, post written by Raymond Chen!!!) would be authoratitive. But with the short, yet quite eventful history of W10, imo all bets are off about what future updates will bring...

Comment: (That said, i expect MS to stick with the current behavior of NTFS, as a change might break some software that relies on such publicized feature details. But i don't trust MS to not butcher a future update, causing (unintentional?) changes to the established behavior.)

Comment: @elgonzo, ok thanks, I will assume files are zeroed in local NTFS. My software would be slower if I need to zero those files myself explicitly. And doing it myself when the SO does it already is a waste.

Comment: @JesúsLópez a FileStream is not necessarily an *NTFS File* stream. Memory cards use Fat for example. Even with NTFS, the stream may point to a *sparse* or *compressed* file. And then, there's ReFS with its deduplication features. You can't make any assumptions about `FileStream`. That's pretty clear from the documentation